# formatting Composite function in f#

Tags: f#, code-formatting

I have a recursive function in f# that iterates a string[] of commands that need to be run, each command runs a new command to generate a map to be passed to the next function.

The commands run correctly but are large and cumbersome to read, I believe that there is a better way to order / format these composite functions using pipe syntax however coming from c# as a lot of us do i for the life of me cannot seem to get it to work.

my command is :

```
 let rec iterateCommands (map:Map<int,string array>) commandPosition  = 
    if commandPosition < commands.Length then
        match splitCommand(commands.[0]).[0] with
        |"comOne" -> 
           iterateCommands (map.Add(commandPosition,create(splitCommand commands.[commandPosition])))(commandPosition+1)
```

The closest i have managed is by indenting the function but this is messy :

```
iterateCommands 
(map.Add
    (commandPosition,create
        (splitCommand commands.[commandPosition])
    )
) 
(commandPosition+1)
```

Is it even possible to reformat this in f#? From what i have read i believe it possible, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
The command/variable types are:
commandPosition - int
commands - string[]
splitCommand string -> string[]
create string[] -> string[]
map : Map<int,string[]>
```

and of course the map.add map -> map + x

Comment: Please share the definitions of the functions you wish to compose, or, at least, their types.

Comment: i have edited my answer to include the types of all the functions and variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be a bit easier to compose the call if you changed the arguments around:

```
let rec iterateCommands commandPosition (map:Map<int,string array>) =
    // ...
```

That would enable you to write something like:

```
splitCommand commands.[commandPosition]
|> create
|> (fun x -> commandPosition, x)
|> map.Add
|> iterateCommands (commandPosition + 1)
```

The fact that `commandPosition` appears **thrice** in the composition is, in my opinion, a design smell, as is the fact that the type of this entire expression is `unit`. It doesn't look particularly functional, but since I don't understand exactly what this function attempts to do, I can't suggest a better design.

If you don't control `iterateCommands`, and hence can't change the order of arguments, you can always define a standard functional programming utility function:

```
let flip f x y = f y x
```

This enables you to write the following against the original version of `iterateCommands`:

```
splitCommand commands.[commandPosition]
|> create
|> (fun x -> commandPosition, x)
|> map.Add
|> (flip iterateCommands) (commandPosition + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what i was after =)
iterateCommands goes through each command executing functions on a passed map and once all the commands are completed a text file is generated and the application ends. 

I did not believe that the iterateCommands function required anything other then a unit type as once the function is completed the application exits would you recommend changing this in anyway currently the function call is iterateCommands Map.empty 0 soon to be iterateCommands 0 Map.empty?

Comment: @Matthewkingston Right, if it's the 'top' function, `unit` is a perfectly fine return type. My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

It's often hard to make out what is going on in a big statement with multiple inputs. I'd give names to the individual expressions, so that a reader can jump into any position and have a rough idea what's in the values used in a calculation, e.g.

```
let inCommands = splitCommand commands.[commandPosition]
let map' = map.Add (commandPosition, inCommands)
iterateCommands map' inCommands
```

Since I don't know what is being done here, the names aren't very meaningful. Ideally, they'd help to understand the individual steps of the calculation.